# Can you change a vote if a post is changed as a result of your edit?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I know that votes are locked until the post is edited.

Once I downvoted a post and left a comment. As it were, when I returned to it, the OP had incorporated my comment into his answer, allowing me to change my downvote.

Suppose that I had been the one to make the change (I have enough rep on that site to edit.) Would that then have allowed me to upgrade my own downvote?

Comment: Yes. Your own edits also unlock your vote.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've done this myself.

Comment: Thanks to the two people above. I thought that might be the case, but I wanted to know "for sure."

Comment: Yes, this is possible. I have done it too.